# Offline behavior of Salesforce Mobile SDK

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios

I am using the following code:

```
[[SFAuthenticationManager sharedManager] loginWithCompletion:self.initialLoginSuccessBlock failure:self.initialLoginFailureBlock];
```

Now my question is what happens if the device is offline in this situation? Salesforce1 seems to break if you try to logout while offline. What would be a good way to handle this case in my code, because neither of the blocks seems to be called, not even the failure block.

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered networkFailureAuthErrorHandler in SFAuthenticationManager Class Reference, looks like a possible solution.